# SSO Not working with API when using swagger or postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am trying to make a single login session over the entire project environment. I want users to have only a single sign-on session, let it be on the website, web app, or application connected via `api` or `web` guards.
The website and web app worked fine but when I tried calling the same function by API using postman or swagger I get `500 Internal Server Error`. I am not sure why am I getting it because there is no such error displayed in the response.

**`authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())` in Login Controller**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{

    if (! $user->isActive()) {
        auth()->logout();

        return trans('auth.login.deactivated_account');
    }

    event(new UserLoggedIn($user));

    if (config('access.users.single_login')) {
        auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
    }
}
```

Sessions get distracted when done in website and web app but when using postman or swagger it's not working, I am not sure why?